# specialization of not template function inside template class

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have this template class which has member functions and they are not template functions.

```
template <class T> class myclass {
    T x;
public:
    myclass(T a);
    T getx() { return x; }
};

// Explicit specialization for int.
template <> class myclass<int> {
    int x;
public:
    myclass(int a) {
        cout << "Inside myclass<int> specialization\n";
        x = a * a;
    }
    int getx() { return x; }
};


int main()
{

    myclass<int> i(10);
    cout << "int: " << i.getx() << "\n";

    myclass<double> d(10.1);
    cout << "double: " << d.getx() << "\n\n";

    myclass<float> f(5);
    cout << "float: " << f.getx() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I was thinking if I could specialize my constructor , something like:

```
myclass<char>::myclass(char a)
{
    x = a;
}
```

and I tried some different ways 
like:

```
template<class T>
myclass<T>::myclass(T a)
{
    x = a;
}
template <>
myclass<char>::myclass(char a)
{
    x = a;
}//Error: explicit specialization; 'myclass<char>::myclass(T)' has already been instantiated
```

but I failed to do so. I thought since my constructor function is not a template function ,this is not possible.

but then in this code:

```
template <class T>
class simpleClass
{
private:
    T data;
public:
    simpleClass(T n);
    void show();
};

//*************
simpleClass<int>::simpleClass(int a)
{
    data = a;
};
template <class  T>
simpleClass<T>::simpleClass(T n)
{
    data = n;
}
//******************
template <class  T>
void simpleClass<T>::show()
{
    cout << data << endl;
}


int main()
{
    simpleClass<int> x(25);
    cout << "int x = ";
    x.show();
    simpleClass<string> str("computer science");
    cout << "string str = ";
    str.show();
    simpleClass<double> d(1.25);
    cout << "double d = ";
    d.show();
    cin.get();
}
```

I add this:

```
simpleClass<int>::simpleClass(int a)
{
    data = a;
};
```

and program worked.

I have learned about templates recently and I don't if what I trying to do is legal or no, and if it's possible how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

my specialization of the primary template occurs after the explicit specialization. That was the error.

it was:

```
// Explicit specialization for int.
template <> class myclass<int> {
    int x;
public:
    myclass(int a) {
        cout << "Inside myclass<int> specialization\n";
        x = a * a;
    }
    int getx() { return x; }
};
template <>
myclass<char>::myclass(char a)
{
    x = a;
}
```

but it should be like this:

```
template <>
myclass<char>::myclass(char a)
{
    x = a;
}

// Explicit specialization for int.
template <> class myclass<int> {
    int x;
public:
    myclass(int a) {
        cout << "Inside myclass<int> specialization\n";
        x = a * a;
    }
    int getx() { return x; }
};
```

However ,I have no idea why is that important, any explanation would be appreciated.